# DateTime::diff() isn't affected by timezone but always return same value

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am adding auction-based data to my system.  For example:

```
user's timezone  is : `America/Denver`
auction start time is : Thu, 21 Jun 2012 03:46:22 AM
auction period : 1 day.
auction end time : Fri, 22 Jun 2012 03:46:22 AM
```

I store all these information as it is in my DB (i.e. *all stored time based on user's timezone*).

Now I want the actual **difference between end time and current time** (of America/Denver timezone).

I used [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functions

> so even I don't convert the timezone; it returns same difference (and that is wrong too).

My PHP code is below; you can also find it at [CodePad](http://codepad.org/B5bDkRWO)

```
$end_time = 'Fri, 22 Jun 2012 03:46:22 AM';
$tz = 'America/Denver';
dateDifference($end_time,$tz);

function dateDifference($end, $tz = NULL)
    {
      $owner_tz = new DateTimeZone($tz);
      //var_dump($owner_tz->getName()); 

      $from  = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('GMT'));     
      $from ->setTimeZone($owner_tz);

      $to = new DateTime($end,new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
      /* @Note:I have commented below setTimeZone() because I have already stored 
       * `end time` as per user's  timezone, So I dont need to convert it again 
       * into user's timezone.you can un-comment below line. 
       * it doesn't affect the results anyways.
       */
     //$to ->setTimeZone($owner_tz);        

    //procedural style using date_diff()
    $interval = date_diff($from, $to);        
    var_dump($interval); 

    // OO style using dateTime::diff()
    $interval = $from->diff($to);       
    var_dump($interval);     
}
```

Returns:

```
object(DateInterval)[4]
  public 'y' => int 0
  public 'm' => int 0
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 16
  public 'i' => int 40
  public 's' => int 24
  public 'invert' => int 0
  public 'days' => int 6015
```

**References:**

- [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
- [`DateTime::diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
- [`DateTime::setTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)
- [Handling timezone conversion with PHP DateTime](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/03/21/handling-timezone-conversion-with-php-datetime/)

Comment: Storing date/time information based on the users timezone is a very bad practice, what if the user changed his/her timezone? A good practice is storing all date/time information WITHOUT timezone (like an UTC timestamp), this way you can minimalize the amount of converting and calculating operations so you only need to worry about setting the correct timezone when outputting a date/time to the user.

Comment: my column datatype is `datetime` , so what changes I need to do when i store, as post data of datetime  coming as user's timezone

Comment: I'm not saying you need to change your application, it was just a suggestion. Have you put date_default_timezone_set somewhere to make sure your server time is correct?

Comment: yes, i have set it in my config file. but your idea is really good. i hev slipped this thought before

Comment: but here point is why `date_diff` display wrong results??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, so i would like to share

Actually I have set default timezone in `config.inc.php` file as below

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

then I check the **current time and timezone of MySQL server** from phpmyadmin with below query

```
SELECT NOW(), SYSDATE(), @@global.time_zone , @@session.time_zone , 
      TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , CONVERT_TZ( NOW( ) , @@session.time_zone ,  '+00:00' )) 
      AS OFFSET
```

This return the `OFFSET` value **+05:30**

#### solution steps:

- First I changed the timezone of mySQL Server to **GMT/UTC +00:00** ( I have **super** privilage on mySQL server)

  ```
  SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00';
  ```
- We save the date and time using `start_date = NOW()` ( column datatype: `DATETIME` )

Now there is 2 way to get date and time as per user's timezone (`America/Denver`)

#### first method ( using PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php))

```
 /*
   * first set timezone as GMT.
   * This is MUST because default timezone is differ from user timezone  
  */     
    $gmt = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
    $user_tz = 'America/Denver';
    $st = new DateTime($row[`start_date`], $gmt);
    // now set user timezone
    $st->setTimezone($user_tz );
    $stime = $qt->format('r');
    echo $stime;
```

#### second method (using  MySQL [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp))

```
#$retrieve data from server in timestamp
$qry = "SELECT `start_date`,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start_date`) AS sTimestamp FROM..."  
$st = new DateTime('@'.$row['sTimestamp ']);                     
$stime = $st->format('r');
echo $stime;
```

**Note :** dont change `start_date`  to  timestamp with `strtotime()`. It will return different value  from the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`
i.e.

```
 strtotime($row['start_date']) !== $row['sTimestamp']
```

Answer (score 1):

On the following lines you're basically saying that the end date is in GMT while it should be in America/Denver time:

```
$to = new DateTime($end, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```

Then you intent to convert it to America/Denver time but since you created the date using the GMT timezone this would have been wrong anyway.

```
// $to ->setTimeZone($owner_tz);
```

This will create the end date using the users timezone which is probably what you are looking for:

```
$to = new DateTime($end, $owner_tz);
```

Comment: No! i have commented that line. i dont want to change it because end time is already saved as per user's timezone at the timing of adding auction.

Comment: As i said, you intent to do that but the first line is where you made your mistake. let me rephrase the answer a bit.

Comment: there is no difference, both are equivalent . you can check.so
`new DateTime($end, $owner_tz);` === `new DateTime($end,new DateTimeZone('GMT')->setTimeZone($owner_tz);`