# How to store time properly for user defined timezone?

Tags: php, date

How to store time properly so that the timezone can be changed later with user defined timezones? How do you typically do this using the DateTime class?

For example:

You run a forum script.

Your server's local time is US

User A is from EU

User B is from JP

User A posted and sees the time based on his local time in EU.

User B sees User A's post on his local time in JP.

My question is what timezone should you store the time. And how do you typically do this using DateTime class?

Comment: Title is longer than content.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: i have faced same problem before some days. see my question and answer too [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137425/datetimediff-isnt-affected-by-timezone-but-always-return-same-value)

Comment: @Pekka Edited my question with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the time in UTC format, for stability and consistency.

Each user should have his preference saved in the database, in the form of **[PHP's known timezones](http://il.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)**.

Then, when displaying, change the time to the correct time zone.

```
$time = "13:37 2012-12-21";
$datetime = new DateTime($time);
$user_timezone = new DateTimeZone($user_timezone_from_the_database);
$datetime->setTimezone($user_timezone);
$datetime->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
```

Would yield the correct date/time for the user.

Comment: Some say, it must be saved in GMT or UTC. But as you said you it should be saved as I received it. For example @diEcho comment above says save it to GMT first.

So I guess it doesn't matter what's the default timezone in my script as long as it's permanent (i.e., defaults to US only).

Is this correct?

Comment: The default timezone is your system's (server's) timezone. Saving it in the user's timezone may cause problems should he change it.

Comment: For the purpose of portability (i.e., some rogue admin changed the timezone or the application moved to a new server), will this have implications? Should it be stored in GMT like @diEcho comment above?

Comment: @IMB: Aye, saving it as UTC can be a smart thing to do. That can be done by changing the time as received to `new DateTimeZone('Etc/UTC');`