# Date conversion in php 1970-01-01

Tags: php

Hi all I am using date conversion as bellow

```
$startdate='12/10/2012'; 
$newstartdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startdate));
```

some time it works but some time it shows **1970-01-01**

Example: 12/10/2012 works
         13/10/2012 does not works shows 1970-01-01

Comment: It's a best-practice to use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) component instead primitive functions.

Answer (score 5):

See PHP's [date and time formats page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If you use `/` characters to delimit your date, it treats it as `mm/dd/yy`. Years only have 12 months.

For dates in a sensible order, use hyphen characters.

```
$startdate='12-10-2012';
$newstartdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startdate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to specify the date format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '13/10/2012');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: yes, I have many reason. First it depends on timezone of server.

Comment: @diEcho When you treat a date string, it always depends on timezone. What do you mean by `it depends on timezone`?

Comment: means it takes server timezone. and when we upload our website and we have no control over server timezone. either you have to set timezone before using datetime:: functions

Comment: you can see multiple proelms regarding dateTime on SO itself. see : http://beckleyworks.com/2011/06/17/php-datetime-bug/

Comment: once i also faced same problem, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137425/datetimediff-isnt-affected-by-timezone-but-always-return-same-value

Comment: @diEcho Still don't make sense, you also need to set timezone if not using DateTime function, don't you?

Comment: Please refer my links. I am unable to express properly what i want to say. Sorry for bad english

Comment: @diEcho What you posted is not a bug but wrong use of DateTime, if you want to construct DateTime form timestamp, you could use `DateTime::setTimestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): `The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format...`

The date `13/10/2012` in "English" (the documentation is wrong about this; it should say "US American") format means the tenth day of the thirteenth month. The thirteenth month doesn't exist in the Gregorian calendar and hence `strtotime` gives a failure result 0, which if used as a Unix timestamp, converts to 1970-01-01.

Use [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to handle differently formatted dates.

Comment: `13/10/2012` means the 13th day of the 10th month in England. It is the American format that reverses the month and day. (The documentation is a bit poor there, you need to dig deeper into the Date and Time formats page for a proper explanation.)

Comment: @Quentin sorry. I was just quoting the documentation. I am Dutch myself and we are also using dd-mm-yyyy format. Note however I do not say it is 'in England' but 'in English format'. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because PHP assumes "12/10/2012" to be the 10th of December 2012 (which is fine) and "13/10/2012" would be the 10th of an undefined month, hence it can't calculate it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help. It replaces `/` with `-`:

```
$startdate='12/10/2012'; 
$date1 = strtr($startdate, '/', '-');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```

Comment: You could improve this answer and explain *why* replacing `/` with `-` solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the above mentioned date class and links to render the output, however if you still stuck with the usage try doing it in this way (just a learning method to look into more in PHP, however this is very bad piece of code :P )

```
$startdate1='13/10/2012'; 
$myarr = explode('/',$startdate1);

$mynewdate = $myarr[1].'/'.$myarr[0].'/'.$myarr[2];

$newstartdate1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($mynewdate));

echo $newstartdate1;
```

Comment: Please do not give answers that teach bad programming. Never do date arithmetic and parsing yourself (you even admit it). There are many libraries and tools out there. For example `strftime`.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thx for the info, but i clearly mentioned this is a very bad way..the date format he is actually using is wrong, but i just posted this that allows him to enhance his vision in coding/date time handling bcoz in real life sometimes u may have to stand apart from the white line ;)

Comment: I understand, but I think we should try to give the best answer, and also 'teach' good programming. If you encounter this question now, you'll see your advice and people will not read your comment, but just blindly copy the code, see that it works and there is another piece of bad code in the world. Especially in PHP, which already has a very bad image in the computing world. Just my two cents.

Comment: @BartFriederichs very true +1 for "Especially in PHP, which already has a very bad image in the computing world" :) I love to share whether good/bad in php that is how i learn php :) Thx for ur every word :)